# JAlerts is being displayed without boarder and layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application , and I need to use the JAlerts mentioned in this link:-

```
http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/
```

I have included the related scripts and Css as follow:-

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tms").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/tms.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.jalert.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.jalert.packed.js"
                        ));

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/templete").Include(


     "~/Content/jalert.css",
     "~/Content/PagedList.css"));
```

But the alert is being displayed without layout and boarders as follow:-

[image]

Comment: Check for CSS files to be correctly loaded. BTW, quite strange path: "~/Content/templete"   don't you mean "~/Content/template" instead

Comment: i do not think that this is a problem as the bundle name is templete and i am referencing ti as templete also..